# How to increase exporting row limit in datagrip postgresql

Tags: postgresql, export, sql-insert, datagrip

I am trying to export some rows from postgresql table in Datagrip in SQL-Insert-Multirow format. I managed to export 410k rows but when number was above 6 million rows Datagrip throws exception. Is there a way to increase export limit. I couldn't find any resource. I tried to in

> VM options :  -Xmx2048m

I solved I guess memory problem but now I am getting this error [57014] ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query for reading data during export is timing out. There's `statement_timeout` parameter in the Postgres configuration file. You may increase the value of this parameter on the Postgres server or pass `-c statement_timeout=<minutes>` parameter to the JDBC driver of your data source properties. See the `options` property for more information [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connection-parameters)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+A`, type *Memory Settings*

[image]

Then, change the setting:

[image]

Comment: I already tried this but it is probably related to statement time out